# CRC Calculation Conversion of Input and Polynomial

Tags: java

I am doing a CRC calculation program. I am given the CRC polynomial in binary. I also have an ASCII input file, which I read in as `String`:

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345a"

Comment: String#toCharArray() ?

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) might be useful.

Comment: I'd look for a library to do the CRC calculation. Most likely you want the data as a byte array, not in hex.

Comment: Could you please (maybe?)  rewrite your question? I haven't understood a single thing.

Comment: Or at least specify `some calculations`

Comment: A char as any other numerical value is not decimal or hexadecimal. You can format it as decimal or hexadecimal when you display it (convert to String).

Comment: How do you usually convert to hex? Maybe that is where I am going wrong?

Comment: @user6134432 please define what you mean with 'hex'

Comment: @Distjubo Like base hex. Like for example a = 61, b = 62, and so on.I think that's how the conversion goes. And apparently there is another conversion format for hex.

Comment: @user6134432 For that you can just convert a char to an int, as they are both primitives. E.g for the lowercase a that would be (int)'a'. If you want to print that as a hex string use Integer.toHexString(). So Integer.toHexString('a') results in "61".

Comment: What I'm trying to say: In java, chars are numbers.

Comment: @Distjubo Right I get that, but I am not sure if that is what I am supposed to be doing. Because I can't really do any calculations with a String. I edited this post and added my program assignment description, maybe that could help?

Comment: @user6134432 I recently wrote a [library](https://github.com/Distjubo/DoofAffe/blob/master/de/distjubo/doofaffe/Common.java) which also has to calculate a checksum from bytes, so you could just fully read the file (ascii or not, doesn't matter) to a byte array and do something similar to me

Comment: @Distjubo Sorry, I am new at this I took a look at it, what does the 0x3d notation mean I see you have a bunch like 0xD0?

Comment: @user6134432 Thats a whole different story. For your assignment, read 64 bytes of data at a time into a byte array, print it out using `System.out.println(new String(bytes, "ASCII"));`and then calculate the checksum using your amazing formula. Those notations let me create bytes using hexcodes btw. The real interesting method in the file I linked is `getChecksum(byte[] bytes)`

Comment: And to clear up all  the confusion about hex and what not, in Java, a number is represented by its value, not the characters and the radix which make up that value. so 0xA is the same as 10.

Comment: @user6134432 That assignment is confusing. Do you have to calculate the crc for each 64-byte-array individually?

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](http://pastebin.com/srP7N2K8)? I have no idea if this is what you are after, but should be a start. Actually, I used CRC-16, I never heard of CRC-15...

Comment: @Distjubo just realized I started this off like completely wrong so I am starting from scratch. I have a question though how do I read the ASCII (only 32 through 127) values from a file?

Comment: Look at the paste I linked. You have your Byte Array, (Array of numbers representing ASCII chars), and you convert that Array into a string using `new String(bytes, "ASCII.") `.

Comment: If you want to convert a single Byte into the representing ASCII Char, simply cast it like that: `(char)byte`

Comment: I will look into that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.
But converting a string to a char array is as easy as calling toCharArray on it.

```
"foo".toCharArray();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean, you need a char[] you can do it so:

```
"abc...".toCharArray();
```

or

```
new char[] {'a','b','c'};
```

Else i don't know what do you mean.

Comment: Then why post an answer? Plus was not the answer you posted already in the comments?

Comment: Comment = Comment, Answer = Answer